# Error : column "drive.cs1_pdm_d_mini" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make a pourcentage in Postgres but it doesn't work, please help me

```
SELECT 
   (CS1_PDM_D_Mini + CS2_PDM_D_Mini + CS3_PDM_D_Mini)  / 
 SUM(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) + SUM(CS2_PDM_D_Mini) + SUM(CS3_PDM_D_Mini)
  AS My_CS_PDM_D_Mini
FROM mytable
```

I've got the following error :

> column "drive.cs1_pdm_d_mini" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

FINALLY Edit :

Hey guy,s thanks a lot for your help, finally, i've ended up with this :

```
(COALESCE(sum(Drive.CS1_PDM_D_Mini),0)+COALESCE(sum(Drive.CS2_PDM_D_Mini),0)+COALESCE(sum(Drive.CS3_PDM_D_Mini),0)) / 
CASE  ((count(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) + count(CS2_PDM_D_Mini) + count(CS3_PDM_D_Mini)))  
    WHEN 0 THEN 1 
ELSE  
((count(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) + count(CS2_PDM_D_Mini) + count(CS3_PDM_D_Mini))) 

END AS My_CS_PDM_D_Mini,
```

Added a CASE for managing divide by zero !

Comment: The error message says it all.

Comment: I am not sure if postgresql supports CTEs but this look like a CTE job

Comment: As the error states, you need to add a `group by` statement. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: What is your goal here? Error is pretty clear

Comment: CTE or not (supported), OP has to decide what to return! Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: So which group by am i supposed to add i dont understand.

Comment: @nick what is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct that you're trying to work out the fraction of the value each row has over the total of all rows, the query below should do it.

```
SELECT 
  (CS1_PDM_D_Mini + CS2_PDM_D_Mini + CS3_PDM_D_Mini)  / 
    (SUM(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) OVER () + SUM(CS2_PDM_D_Mini) OVER () + SUM(CS3_PDM_D_Mini) OVER ())
  AS My_CS_PDM_D_Mini
FROM mytable
```

The `SUM(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) OVER ()` bit uses a Window expression to get the SUM of all rows instead of just looking at the current row.

Window functions described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

This will just return a list of fractions, eg: 0.5 for the row that is 50% of the total.  So you'd probably want to return the key for the row if there is one.  This can be added to the select
eg:

```
SELECT 
  meaningful_row_key,
  (CS1_PDM_D_Mini + CS2_PDM_D_Mini + CS3_PDM_D_Mini)  / 
    (SUM(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) OVER () + SUM(CS2_PDM_D_Mini) OVER () + SUM(CS3_PDM_D_Mini) OVER ())
  AS My_CS_PDM_D_Mini
FROM mytable
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is not needed for window functions. -- Also, OP's query doesn't have parenthesis around its `SUM()` calls, so it cannot be re-arranged into a single call (but not sure if that's intended though, your use case at least have some sense).

Comment: @pozs good point on the group.  I'll update the examples.   Regarding the SUM, I hadn't considered if one of the values was NULL, so I'll update that as well.

Comment: no, I mean the original expression does not use parenthesis around its `SUM()` calls, so actually it divides with only `SUM(CS1_PDM_D_Mini)` and not with the sum of those 3 `SUM()`s. But again, this may be unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this

```
SELECT SUM(CS1_PDM_D_Mini) + SUM(CS2_PDM_D_Mini) + SUM(CS3_PDM_D_Mini) / 
       (CS1_PDM_D_Mini + CS2_PDM_D_Mini + CS3_PDM_D_Mini) AS My_CS_PDM_D_Mini
FROM mytable
group by CS1_PDM_D_Mini
    ,CS2_PDM_D_Mini
    ,CS3_PDM_D_Mini
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try, i've just edited the message because the calcul was inverted sorry, but i understand what you say, its is really good